# Unity battery icon missing

Tags: indicator, battery

Whenever I plug in my cell phone, my Unity battery indicator changes to look like this:

[image: No battery icon]

Without the phone, it acts as expected and shows the actual battery. Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: What changes did you make to the system that resulted in this behavior? I cannot reproduce your results. Does it happen when you boot from a live media as well?

Comment: @ElderGeek The last major change was installing KDE. Let me get back to you about the live disk, as I don't know where it is.